# Collection View twitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have horizontal collection view with custom collection view cell and paging enabled. Size of the cell is the same like size of the collection view (always is just one cell visible). Problem is when I started to scroll to another cell I have a twitch, and that twitch is just on the first scroll, latter everything working fine. I don't have heavy operation in cellForItemAtIndexPath method, just show data from array.

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: I made new project from scratch, don't set any data in cellForItemAtIndexPath and I got the same results. I have '[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"thoughtCell"];' in viewDidLoad, and 'CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"thoughtCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];' in cellForItemAtIndexPath.